# socket.io connected false when try connect in onClick function in a tag

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

i'm using hash router in react-router-dom, so socket doesn't close after move url

i'm trying to connect socket.io in onClick function of a tag
On Server, client success connection 
but client's socket object `connected` is false

is it because browser move page?
i don't know why, help please

```
function GameButton() {
  function connectSocket() {
    return socketIo.connect(`http://localhost:3000/game`);
  }

  return (
    <a href="/#/gameplay">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const gameSocket = connectSocket();
          console.log(gameSocket.connected); // false
        }}
      />
    </a>
  );
}
```

thank you

Comment: its because of <a> tag,try to put button outside <a>

Comment: move the button outside the `a` tag

Comment: thank you! it really helps me